Slow and steady wins

Solve on Penpa+
Across
3. Round disks of metal, carbon and hydrogen found inside Mars and Venus? (9)
7. He sang "Heartbreak Hotel" and "Hotel Quenya", for example (6)
9. Forthcoming Pixar film show (7)
10. Misbehaving rebels, having no right, stole perhaps Benjamin Netanyahu's ornaments (8)
11. Onetime seabird supporter is on the outside (10)
12. Mythology in Tolkien's story glosses over source of Treebeard's energy (4)
13. Department puts up with grave breach of trust, protecting nothing that makes sense (2,6,2,6)
19. Blue Man Group undressed? (4)
21. Fiddle around the first letter in Haifa to describe statue not described by 13 across? (3,7)
24. Sweet actor Malek's in the grips of terrible UTI (8)
25. For example, Aerosmith's 15 down may get asked if they're off theirs (7)
26. Many in Australia residing in burrows (6)
27. Massive snake, swallowing man, destroyed US art text from long ago (4,5)
Down
1. Like some eggs after start of breakfast (6)
2. Open declaration of war unveiled; volunteer leader unexpectedly AWOL (6)
3. Stop tiny dog biting head of lettuce (4)
4. If a female dances, male perhaps gets up and joins (7)
5. From atmospheric hole, radiation leads to serious health concern (7)
6. Jafe abandoned vessel with captain in secondary storyline (7)
7. Regularly seen young kangaroo raising its tail in front of real fan (7)
8. Small river in Italy surrounds extremely little city on the Campanian coast (7)
14. Mexican dish from outskirts of Tijuana, a major city in Latin America (7)
15. Harry Dunne and Lloyd Christmas, could be twins? It gets wild! (7)
16. Superhero pouts endlessly, having received dismissive reaction? (3-4)
17. Men wanting balls and cue shun running (7)
18. Filter right amount of radiation (7)
20. Slow and steady wins the race, and others are down forever (6)
22. Manhattan neighbourhood's lacking large places for 17 down (6)
23. It contains taigas and tigers like before, I essentially explained (4)

COMPLETED GRID

 

ACROSS

 3. PLANCHETS - C + H in PLANETS
 7. ELVISH [Quenya] - ELVIS + H [NATO phonetic]
 9. UPFRONT - UP + FRONT
 10. BEJEWELS - (-r)EBELS* [having no right] + JEW
 11. EXTERNALLY - EX + TERN + ALLY
 12. LORE - LO(-t)R + E
 13. IT STANDS TO REASON - IT [department] + STANDS + TREASON protecting O [nothing]
 19. AQUA - (-m)A(-n) + (-s)QUA(-d)
 21. THE THINKER - TINKER around HETH (per OP) [original slightly off: TINKER around THE H_]
 24. TIRAMISU - RAMI'S in UTI*
 25. ROCKERS ddef.
 26. DOZENS - OZ in DENS
 27. KAMA SUTRA - KAA + M + (US ART)*

DOWN

 1. BEATEN - B_ + EATEN (&lit!)
 2. AVOWAL - _A_ + V_ + AWOL*
 3. PLUG - PUG + L_
 4. AFFIRMS - (IF A F)* + SEX<
 5. CHOLERA - _C HOLE RA_
 6. SUBPLOT - SUB + P(-i)LOT
 7. ENJOYER - sEeN + JOEY [reorder, with tail raised] + R [real]
 8. SALERNO - S [small] + ARNO + L_E
 14. TAQUITO - T_A + QUITO
 15. NITWITS - (TWINS IT)*
 16. SHE-HULK - SULK(-s) + HEH
 17. EUNUCHS - (CUE SHUN)* [heh]
 18. SIEVERT - SIEVE + RT
 20. ADAGES - A + D + AGES
 22. HAREMS - HAR(-l)EM'S
 23. ASIA - AS + I + _A_


21a: rot13(Gur svefg yrggre va gur jbeq Unvsn angviryl vf URGU gur Uroerj yrggre... Cebonoyl fubhyq unir yrsg bhg gur 'gur' sebz gur pyhr gb nibvq gur bgure vagrecergngvba!)

Got it, will update. Thanks for another fun puzzle :-)
